Question About Axiom Group 5 in Enderton's Logic Textbook
In Enderton's Textbook "Introduction to Mathematical Logic", he specifies 6 Axiom Groups on Page 112 Chapter 2.4 which are used in conjunction with their generalizations, a set of hypothesis $\Gamma$ and Modus Ponens to form deductions in first order logic.
The Axiom Group I am confused about is Axiom Group 5, i.e for any variable $x$, $x=x$. The confusion I am having is that I have a feeling it should be for every term $t$, not just for every variable.
The reason is that I have been struggling to come up with a deduction  $\vdash f(x) = f(x)$. I tried using Axiom Group 6 to obtain $(x=x) \rightarrow (f(x) = f(x) \rightarrow f(x) = f(x))$, and then using modus ponens, but this is useless as it just gives $(f(x) = f(x) \rightarrow f(x) = f(x))$, which is useless because I'm trying to show $f(x) = f(x)$. I tried using tautologies too, but I just get stuck because I can't find a tautology that gets me where I want. And I can't say because $x=x$ then $f(x) = f(x)$, because $"="$ here is just the equality symbol, not an actual assertion of equality. So  I feel stuck because the other Axiom Groups just lead me in circles.
However, there should be a proof to this, by completeness of first order logic, as $\vDash f(x) = f(x)$ is obviously true (for any structure $\mathcal{U}$ and variable assignment $s$ for $\mathcal{U}$, $\mathcal{U} \vDash f(x) = f(x) [s]$ is true iff $f^{\mathcal{U}}(s(x)) = f^{\mathcal{U}}(s(x))$, which is true obviously by properties of functions.)
So my question is: should Axiom Group 5 include terms and this was a typo? Or is there some deduction $\vdash f(x) = f(x)$ that exists that I am just missing?

Not really an issue.
See page 112, regarding logical axioms:

The logical axioms are then all generalizations of wffs of the following forms...,

that means that we have to read the axiom as: $\forall x (x=x)$.
Then, apply Axiom 2: $∀x α → α^x_t$ to it and we get: $t=t$.
